# Localhost:8080 not loading - glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish

I have installed Glassfish webserver version 10, successfully in MAC OS.
I had no problem intalling or starting the server.
the server is running, but when i try to run glassfish in port:8080, it is not loading and i get a blank page.
however, localhost 4848 is loading and I can see webspace enabled there.
I have tried with jdk5,6 and reinstalling things, but in vain
anyone know a solution.........

Answer (score 2):

You can easily create a second domain with Glassfish.  This will tell you if there is a problem with the domain or the installation of Glassfish.

```
asadmin create-domain --adminport 4949 --instanceport 9090 domain2
```

Now connect to the admin port on 4949

http://localhost:4949

Login and password are admin, adminadmin

Also check the log directory of each domain:

```
$GLASSFISH/domains/domain1/logs
$GLASSFISH/domains/domain2/logs
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the `domain.xml` under `sun/sdk/domains/config`

Listed in this link http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=250531

- search page for domain.xml -

This corrected my problem easyfix.

Comment: This is the easiest solution. Change the listening port to "8081" or something besides "8080" in the domain.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Check if the port is firewalled. I once spent considerable amount of time with Tomcat on Vista before I nailed the silly issue.

Answer (score 0):

did you check what HTTP ports is enabled for your appserver ? in the management interface click on 'Application Server' then the 'General' tab , you will see something like  :

HTTP Port(s): 30500,30502,30501

maybe your glassfish is using port 8080 for something else - or you have another webserver running on that port somewhere ?